# Hook Up Command for BackKeyPress in XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

Is there a way to hook up the BackKeyPressed event to a command in a view (XAML)? I'm using MVVM Light.

I have a few login/signup screens that can possibly be shown. If they're in the login/signup process, which is just showing/hiding user controls, I want to be able to intercept the back button so I can show/hide the appropriate control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that I'm not familiar with WP7 development, but I believe MVVM Light handles WPF4 & WP7 similarly:

```
<PhoneApplicationPage
    xmlns:Command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WP7"
    xmlns:Interactivity="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Interactivity:EventTrigger
            EventName="BackKeyPress">
            <Command:EventToCommand
                Command="{Binding BackKeyPressCommand}" />
        </Interactivity:EventTrigger>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
</PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: This does work. Is there a way to have the event args passed in? I tried `BackKeyPressCommand = new RelayCommand<CancelEventArgs>( BackKeyPress );` but the events args are `null` when it hits the `BackKeyPress` method.

Comment: I would like to cancel the event `e.Cancel = true;` when the command is fired.

Comment: Just add `PassEventArgsToCommand="True"` to the `EventToCommand`.

Answer (score 0):

You *might* be able to do this by writing your own BasePage class that inherits from PhoneApplicationPage and that exposes a public event, and which then triggers that event in the `override OnBackKeyPress` method

In your custom page, you can then inherit your new BasePage class instead of PhoneApplicationPage and can then hopefully bind that event to a command in the XAML.

However, in this particular case, I think I might be tempted to use C# rather than XAML - e.g. calling Execute directly in OnBackKeyPress