# Can the back button be handled in Caliburn.Micro on the view model

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation, caliburn.micro

I currently only use ProperyChangedBase as my base class provider. Is there a way to handle the user pressing the back button in Caliburn.Micro from my ViewModel rather than having to do it in the code behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should work
[Hook Up Command for BackKeyPress in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363958/hook-up-command-for-backkeypress-in-xaml)

but with CM you can use cal:Message.Attach="[Event BackKeyPress] etc.

Comment: Cheers, never thought of that!