# Caliburn micro stop app exit

Tags: windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn Micro in my Windows Phone 8 app and I want to prompt the user when they press the back button before the app is exited. Yes I do have a good reason for doing this!

I tried this code but it gets called after the app has exited.

```
    private void _navigationService_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Exit App", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }           
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

i think you are using a wrong event, what my suggestion is:

```
 protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
           if (!NavigationService.CanGoBack)
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Exit App", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
                 {
                  e.Cancel = true;
                 }     
            }            
    }
```

Comment: This works well but has to go in the view. I was looking for something I can put in the view model.

Comment: i think this is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363958/hook-up-command-for-backkeypress-in-xaml

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your View

```
micro:Message.Attach="[Event BackKeyPress] = [Action OnGoBack($eventArgs)]"
```

and create a OnGoBack($eventArgs) in your ViewModel

```
public void OnGoBack(CancelEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Exit App", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
}
```